# Regex to split key value pairs (key: value key: "va lue") from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I'm looking for a regex that will split a string of the following format into an array of key-value pairs.

```
"category: Music artist: \"Chris Martin\" album: \"A head full of dreams\" genre: dance"
```

into

```
["category: Music", "artist: \"Chris Martin\"", "album: \"A head full of dreams\"", "genre: dance"]
```

Also, how do I verify if the string is in the right format like every key has a value and if there are spaces in keys or values, it has to be enclosed in double quotes?

I came up with this to split key-value pairs, but it can only separate if key values are enclosed within quotes and separated by commas

```
/(^[^\s:"]+: *"[^"]+"$)|([^"]+: *[^"]+$)/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get matches instead of splitting the string by the following regex:

```
\w+:.*?(?=\s+\w+:|$)
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mMd3nc/1/)**

**Explanation:**

- `\w+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a word character i.e, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`
- `:` - matches `:`
- `.*?` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character except a newline, as few as possible
- `(?=\s+\w+:|$)` - positive lookahead to make sure that the current position is either followed by end of the line OR by 1+ whitespaces followed by 1+ word characters followed by a `:`

**Code:**

```js
var regex = /\w+:.*?(?=\s+\w+:|$)/gm;
var str = "category: Music artist: \"Chris Martin\" album: \"A head full of dreams\" genre: dance";
var objMatch = regex.exec(str);
var arr = new Array();
while(objMatch!=null)
{
    arr[arr.length] = objMatch[0];
    objMatch = regex.exec(str);
}
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

**OR**, you can perform the split operation using the following regex:

```
\s(?=\w+:)
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mMd3nc/2)**

**Explanation:**

- `\s` - matches a whitespace
- `(?=\w+:)` - positive lookahead to make sure that the current position must be followed by 1+ word-characters followed by `:`

**Code:**

```js
var regex = /\s(?=\w+:)/gm;
var str = "category: Music artist: \"Chris Martin\" album: \"A head full of dreams\" genre: dance";
var arr = str.split(regex);
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: You forgot about two things. One is verifying keys with no values, two is wrapping keys or values within double quotation marks if they include spaces.

Comment: @revo If keys have no values, then my [1st regex](https://regex101.com/r/mMd3nc/4) would work in that case too. But still you are correct. I just kept the example string provided by OP as my reference while attempting to answer this question.

Comment: No it would not if a key with no value occurs at end of input string.

Comment: @Gurman how do I verify if the given string is in the format I've specified? It Should be key-value pairs and enclosed within quotes if key/value has spaces. Both your regexes return true when I do a test with string in wrong format. regex.test(strInWrongFormat)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the matches you want using the this:

```
(\w+):\s?(.+?)(?=\s+\w+:|"?$)
```

or this without the capture groups:

```
\w+:\s?.+?(?=\s+\w+:|"?$)
```

Check out the demo [here](https://regexr.com/3l76h)

**Explanation**

`(\w+):` will match any word ending in a colon, and capture the word part.

The `.+?` will match any character lazily, that is will stop matching whenever the next condition can be satisfied.

The `(?=\s\w+:)` is a look around match, that stops the match when `\s\w+:` is matched. That corresponds to a space followed by a word ending with a colon.